# How to get data this nested list json with volley?

Tags: json, android-studio, android-volley

URL: https://api.alquran.cloud/v1/quran/quran-uthmani

I want to receive the data at this address, but I cannot get data from the list named "surah" in the data.
Can you help me?
How to solve this problem?
I can show the "data" list but I don't know how to get the "surah" arry in it.

My java code:

```js
String url = "https://api.alquran.cloud/v1/quran/quran-uthmani";

                StringRequest istek = new StringRequest( Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject( response );
                            Log.e( "ilkData", "test" );

                            JSONArray kuranMainListe = jsonObject.getJSONArray( "data" );
                            JSONArray surahMainListe = kuranMainListe.getJSONArray( 0 );


                            for (int i = 0; i < surahMainListe.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject sureler = surahMainListe.getJSONObject( i );
                                JSONObject sure = sureler.getJSONObject( "Surahs" );
                                int sureNumber = sureler.getInt( "number" );
                                String sureName = sureler.getString( "name" );
                                String sureEnName = sureler.getString( "englishName" );
                                String sureEnCeviri = sureler.getString( "englishNameTranslation" );
                                String sureVahiyTuru = sureler.getString( "revelationType" );
                                Log.e( "sureAdi", sureName );


                                JSONArray ayetlerListe = jsonObject.getJSONArray( "ayahs" );
                                for (int a = 0; a < ayetlerListe.length(); a++) {
                                    JSONObject ayetler = ayetlerListe.getJSONObject( a );
                                    int ayetNumber = ayetler.getInt( "number" );
                                    String ayettext = ayetler.getString( "text" );
                                    int ayetnumberInSurah = ayetler.getInt( "numberInSurah" );
                                    int ayetjuz = ayetler.getInt( "juz" );
                                    int ayetmanzil = ayetler.getInt( "manzil" );
                                    int ayetpage = ayetler.getInt( "page" );
                                    int ayetruku = ayetler.getInt( "ruku" );
                                    int ayethizbQuarter = ayetler.getInt( "hizbQuarter" );
                                    String ayetSajda = ayetler.getString( "sajda" );

                                    Log.e( "ayetNumarasi", String.valueOf( ayetNumber ) );

                                }


                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e( "hataCatch", String.valueOf( e ) );
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e( "volleyHata", String.valueOf( error ) );
                    }
                } );
                istek.setRetryPolicy( new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        10000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT ) );
                Volley.newRequestQueue( KuranOkuBendenAyarlar.this ).add( istek );
```

Comment: I fixed this problem. I have overlooked that the curly brackets are "{" object, the square bracket is "[" array.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. I have overlooked that the curly brackets are "{" object, the square bracket is "[" array.